# Recursive function is not working with a pointer

Tags: c

This function aims to return the number of zeroes in a number, num. The function rCountZeros2() passes the result through
the pointer parameter result.
`

```
void rCountZeros2(int num, int *result)
{
    if (num==0)
        return;
    else
    {
        if (num%10==0){
            (*result)++;
            }
        rCountZeros2(num/10, result);

    }
}
```

`

Comment: can you show how you are calling it?  This should work rather nicely

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issues with the logic of your function.

Comment: please show how you called the function, what you saw, and what you expect.

Comment: My guess is you didn't initialize the pointer in the original call, or you didn't initialize the variable that it points to.

Comment: Why not just *return* the result, rather than writing it to a pointer?  But if you want to do it this way, you should *store* the result to the pointer, rather than *adding* the result to what it previously pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See when you are invoking `rCountZeros2()` , my guess is value in variable result is not zero.It may be some garbage value or some other value from previous computation.However with details you have provided it is difficult to provide exact answer.

Kindly try the following standalone program, I got correct answer using your code

```
void rCountZeros2(int num, int *result)
{
    if (num==0)
        return;
    else
    {
        if (num%10==0){
            (*result)++;
            }
        rCountZeros2(num/10, result);

    }
}
int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    int num=12300000;
    rCountZeros2(num, &result);
    printf("number of zeros in %d = %d",num ,result);
}
```

Comment: alright my guess is that the 'garbage value' in my code is an 8 for result. do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: @King_Arthur do```result = 0;``` just before calling the function ```rCountZeros2(num, &result);```

Comment: @King_Arthur mark answer as correct if it worked for you